# LSTM - need help to predict future value?

Tags: prediction, lstm

Will `LSTM` be able to predict the out of sample (future) datasets? In order words, if I have a sales datasets of 2014 - 2016, will `LSTM` be able to predict the sales of 2017?

Let's assume we have the following information. Will `LSTM` be able to predict the datasets for `1-Jan-17` to `1-Dec-17` from the given datasets? If so please provide me with a sample code.

```
Date     Sales 

1-Jan-14 266.1 

1-Feb-14 145.9 

1-Mar-14 183.1 

1-Apr-14 119.3 

1-May-14 180.3 

1-Jun-14 168.5 

1-Jul-14 231.8 

1-Aug-14 224.5 

1-Sep-14 192.8 

1-Oct-14 122.9 

1-Nov-14 336.5 

1-Dec-14 185.9 

1-Jan-15 194.3 

1-Feb-15 149.5 

1-Mar-15 210.1 

1-Apr-15 273.3 

1-May-15 191.4 

1-Jun-15 287 

1-Jul-15 226 

1-Aug-15 303.6 

1-Sep-15 289.9 

1-Oct-15 421.6 

1-Nov-15 264.5 

1-Dec-15 342.3 

1-Jan-16 339.7 

1-Feb-16 440.4 

1-Mar-16 315.9 

1-Apr-16 439.3 

1-May-16 401.3 

1-Jun-16 437.4 

1-Jul-16 575.5 

1-Aug-16 407.6 

1-Sep-16 682 

1-Oct-16 475.3 

1-Nov-16 581.3 

1-Dec-16 646.9
```

Code I have used:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#dataset = pandas.read_csv(r'C:\Users\CHAWALU\Desktop\LSTM\Jupyter notebook\Dmd1hr.csv')
dataset = pandas.read_csv('shampoo.csv')
plt.plot(dataset)
plt.show()
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import math
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load the dataset
#dataframe = pandas.read_csv(r'C:\Users\CHAWALU\Desktop\LSTM\Jupyter notebook\Dmd1hr.csv')
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('shampoo.csv')
dataset = dataframe.values
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
print(len(train), len(test))
# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)
# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 2
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)
# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))
# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=300, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
# invert predictions
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])
# calculate root mean squared error
trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:,0]))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:,0]))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))
# shift train predictions for plotting
trainPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
trainPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, :] = trainPredict
# shift test predictions for plotting
testPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
testPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1, :] = testPredict
# plot baseline and predictions
plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(dataset))
plt.plot(trainPredictPlot)
plt.plot(testPredictPlot)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I have tried the code below but unfortunately, the closest I came is splitting the sample sales into 67 training % and 33 testing % and my forecast is only forecasting for the 33% testing data sets but it never goes beyond 36th time steps.

Comment: Since I could not copy the code here, attached is the github link explaining what I have done so far. 

https://github.com/ukeshchawal/hello-world/blob/master/trial.ipynb

Comment: 'I could not copy the code here"... that is highly unlikely, please edit your question and add the *relevant* parts of your code

Comment: @GrayCygnus Thank you for responding. I have attached my code above along with the question. The question that I have is: How do I use the datasets to predict the future value for 2017 per month? Currently it is using 2014 and 2015 datasets to predict 2016, but I was trying to use the datasets of 2014 to 2016 to predict for 2017.... 
Thank You for getting back to me.

Comment: @Ukesh the reason u can't do predictions from `Jan- 2017` through `Dec-2017` is that you do not have test data for the time period.